# How to use `class-direct-superclasses` and `class-precedence-list` in Steel Bank Common Lisp (SBCL)?

Tags: class, package, namespaces, common-lisp, clos

In tutorials such as [this one](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/clos-tutorial/), one can simply use:

```lisp
CL-USER> (class-precedence-list (find-class (class-name (class-of 123))))
```

In LispWorks they're available via your default package-use-list, in Allegro they're exported from ACLMOP.

But, how to use `class-precedence-list`and `class-direct-superclasses` in SBCL?

Obs.: There is a new version of this tutorial on CLOS via the [The Common Lisp Cookbook](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/clos.html).

Comment: `class-direct-superclasses` is part of the metaobject protocol (MOP) for CLOS, which is not standardised & hence may vary among implementations.  A good starting point is [Closer to MOP](https://github.com/pcostanza/closer-mop) which builds a pretty standard MOP on top of the various implementations.  It's in Quicklisp.

Comment: I'd love if you linked to the more recent Cookbook on Github.

Comment: @Ehvince, it has been added :). I will read the newer version, I am just reading the older material first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SBCL, it is necessary to use package notation importing the symbol from `sb-mop`:

```lisp
CL-USER> (sb-mop:class-direct-superclasses (find-class (class-name (class-of 123))))
(#<BUILT-IN-CLASS COMMON-LISP:INTEGER>)

CL-USER> (sb-mop:class-precedence-list (find-class (class-name (class-of 123))))
(#<BUILT-IN-CLASS COMMON-LISP:FIXNUM> #<BUILT-IN-CLASS COMMON-LISP:INTEGER>
 #<BUILT-IN-CLASS COMMON-LISP:RATIONAL> #<BUILT-IN-CLASS COMMON-LISP:REAL>
 #<BUILT-IN-CLASS COMMON-LISP:NUMBER> #<SB-PCL:SYSTEM-CLASS COMMON-LISP:T>)
```